# CSOM ExecuteQuery Invalid file name while acquiring lists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, client-object-model, csom

I just started learning CSOM, I want to get all lists from specific site provided by user, and display them in WinForms app. Here is the code of acquiring lists:

```
    class ListCheckRepo : IListCheckRepo
{
    public ListCollection GetLists(string url)
    {
        ClientContext clientcontext = new ClientContext(url);
        Web web = clientcontext.Web;
        ListCollection listColl = web.Lists;
        clientcontext.Load(listColl);

        clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
        return listColl;
    }
}
```

The problem is an error "Invalid file name" at ExecuteQuery

> ```
> The file name you specified could not be used.  
> It may be the name of an existing file or directory, 
> or you may not have permission to access the file.
> ```

I Have literally no idea what it means, which file or directory is it talking about. The URL Im providing is a working one, also I was working with msdn documentation while writing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

One of the lists in site was corrupted, and therefore unreadable. Deleting broken list fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below sample code to get the list collection in a site and display them in a console. Change the display code accordingly to use with WinForms.

```
        // ClientContext - Get the context for the SharePoint Site      
        ClientContext clientContext = new 
        ClientContext("http://SiteURL/sites/SP");  

        // Get the SharePoint web  
        Web web = clientContext.Web;  

        // Get the SharePoint list collection for the web   
        ListCollection listColl = web.Lists;  

        // Retrieve the list collection properties   
        clientContext.Load(listColl);  


        // Execute the query to the server.   
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  

        // Loop through all the list   
        foreach(List list in listColl)    
        {  
            // Display the list title and ID    
            Console.WriteLine("List Name: " + list.Title + "; ID: " + 
            list.Id);  
        }
```

Comment: It's exactly the same code as I posted above, but as you said, in console.